# Using ASM to detect possible synchronization deadlock

Tags: java, deadlock, bytecode

consider the following code snippet

```
synchronized (A.class) {
  foo();
  synchronized (B.class) {
    bar();
  }
}
```

And another code where A and B are swapped. This is might cause deadlock, and I'm trying to detect this using ASM (in particular, I only detect if A, B are classes which I know one should NOT synchronize on, eg Exceptions). Currently, I have an Analyzer which uses a SimpleVerifier. Using this, I can obtain the BasicValue on top of the stack and get its Type, but in the code example the internal name would be java/lang/Class, which does not tell me about which class it is. I can't seem to find a simple way to find which class the class represents. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at static or dynamic analysis?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use ASM's [SourceInterpreter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/analysis/SourceInterpreter.html) to track down where the value came from and then evaluate yourself what the value is.

PS: BTW, synchronizing on a Class is a bad idea...

Comment: He might even fancy writing his own Interpreter which operates on a higher-level abstraction e.g. aggregate expressions.